# Where can I find ACROPDFlib.dll 64 bit dll or is there any alternate to use pdf for 64 bit?

Tags: .net, winforms, adobe, 64-bit, pdf-viewer

**Where can i find ACROPDFlib.dll 64 bit dll or is there any alternate to use pdf for 64 bit?
No Matter either its free or Not?**

I want to show PDF Files in my c# WinForm Application. just preview of PDF Files
If i purchased Library from third party than i should be able to show control in the PDF Viewer.

what would you suggest me?
Thanks

Comment: have you searched ACROPDFlib.dll on google?

Comment: Yes but there was no 64 bit version of this DLL

Comment: This GPL(?) library can be used to display PDFs inside a 64bit .NET windforms application: http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/ I haven't tried it though. It was created by a fellow on StackOverflow: HABJAN

Answer (score 4):

i have a solution for you, i think. start [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/75cc92de-1649-431a-a688-3aab16ca86e2/systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception-was-unhandled) and then [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/08adc799-e705-47d1-940c-3f91ef442cec/target-x86-platform-in-vc-express). you aren't going to use a 64bit version of ACROPDFlib because, to my understanding, there is no such dll.
instead what you do is build/compile your code with target platform 'X86'. the steps:

1. On the "Tools" menu, click "Options".
2. Check "Show all settings".
3. Expand "Projects and Solutions and click General".
4. Check "Show advanced build configurations".
5. Click "OK"
6. On the "Build" click "Configuration Manager...".  (Add it if it isn't there)
7. In the "Acitve solution platform:" drop down, click "".
8. In the "Type or select the new platform:" drop down, click "x86".
9. Click "OK".
10. Click "Close".

it toke me a while to understand that, and a long time to try it, and i'm still not sure that it all work as needed, but i did not got an exception. good luck. let me know if it worked

Comment: Liran Thanks for your answer. But if I use these instruction than it will not give me that Performance as I expected from 64 bit .I am switching my application from 32 to 64 bit to improve its performance.

Comment: Yes Its Working But my Requirement is Different as I told you .

Comment: well, unfortunately this is the current only known way i  could find to do this. you can try sending mail to adobe if really need it

Comment: @UmairAslam please accept the answer if you feel it's a good answer